# i am getting a error while using java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

Here is my code:

```
import java.rmi.*;
public interface a extends Remote
{
    public int fun(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
}
```

---

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
public class b extends UnicastRemoteObject implements a
{
    public b() throws RemoteException
    {
    }
    public int fun(int a,int b)
    {
        return(a+b);
    }
}

import java.rmi.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class c
{
    public static void main(String bat[])
    {
        String host="localhost";
        int aa=10,bb=20;
        try
        {
            a ob=(a)Naming.lookup("rmi://"+host+"/a");
            System.out.println(ob.fun(aa,bb));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

import java.rmi.*;
import java.net.*;
public class d
{
    public static void main(String bat[])
    {
        try
        {
            b obb=new b();
            Naming.rebind("rmi:///a",obb);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to run this by first compiling the files using javac. Then using

rmic b
start rmiregistry
java d
I get this error

java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: b_Stub

Comment: Seams to me that you are sending an object ob class `b` to the server and the server does not know anything about class `b` or a stub representing class `b`

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: See my answer in the duplicate.